# background repeat-x with margin/padding

Tags: css, image, background-image, background-repeat

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEoEGJ)

I have two images that shall be one. Concept image:

[image]

The height (outer image) will be always 773px. I want to have the image with an width of 100% without stretching the image. So I need/want to use `reapeat-x`. But since the inner image needs an padding/margin to fit into the outer image this is a bit problematic.

So what I've tried is repeating the outer image and copying the inner image with an `:after` element. But I really dislike this option since it breaks when zooming.

So my question is: How can I deal better with this situation?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @zgood hm? What code are you asking for?

Comment: Sorry I must have missed your CodePen link

Comment: AFAIK there is no way how to mimic `background-repeat` property with elements, which is what you need to achieve. There is experimental feature in firefox called [`element()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element), but it is not supported in other browsers. I think the only solution would be define one div containing the scene and then repeat that scene horizontally with JavaScript.